# Read all images from folder and detect faces, crop and save to new folder

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mat

I'm trying to build a model in which it will read all the images from a given folder and detects the face, crop and save cropped face to a new folder!

Can anyone help me with code as I am receiving an error:

```
cv2.imshow(str(img) , img)

TypeError: mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

code:

```
import glob 
import cv2
import sys
while 1 :
    filename = input("Enter the file name in which images are present =")
    for img in glob.glob(filename+'/*.*'):
        #try :
            var_img = cv2.imread(img)
            cv2.imshow(str(img) , var_img)

    def detect_face(img):

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('opencv-files/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml')
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5);

        if (len(faces) == 0):
            return None, None

        (x, y, w, h) = faces[0]
        return gray[y:y+w, x:x+h], faces[0]
    cv2.imshow(str(img) , img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to imshow the filename instead of the actual array. `glob.glob` returns a list of filenames so your `img` that you're trying to imshow is just a string. You need to read in the image first before you imshow it. You did that in this line: `var_img = cv2.imread(img)` so that means your array is `var_img`. But later you tried to imshow again using just `img`. You can only imshow `var_img` which is an array and not `img` which is a string.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import glob 
import cv2
import sys
import os
def detect_face(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('opencvfiles/lbpcascade_frontalface.xmlv')
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5)
    return faces

filename = input("Enter the file name in which images are present =")

for img in glob.glob(filename+'/*.*'):
    var_img = cv2.imread(img)
    face = detect_face(var_img)
    print(face)
    if (len(face) == 0):
        continue
    for(ex, ey, ew, eh) in face:
        crop_image = var_img[ey:ey+eh, ex:ex+ew]
        cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)  
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join("outputs/",str(img)),crop_image)
```